# How to convert three lists to json?

Tags: python, json, list

I have a three lists which I need to convert to json using python, It should be in a specific order, each item of `a` should be key in which it should have four keys of each item of `b` and there values should be every four items of `c` corresponding to it. If you don't understand, please see the example.

```
a = ["a","b","c"]
b = ["m","n","o","p"]
c = [1,2,3,4,"z","y","x","w","aa","ab","ac","ad"]
```

convert the above data into this

```
dic = {
    "a": {
        "m": 1,
        "n": 2,
        "o":3,
        "p":4
    },
    "b": {
        "m": "z",
        "n": "y",
        "o":"x",
        "p":"w"       
    },
    "c":{
        "m": "aa",
        "n": "ab",
        "o":"ac",
        "p":"ad"
    }
}
```

any suggestions will be strongly appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice might help you, code it yourself tho;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single line solution would be to use dictionary comprehension like this.

```py
a = ["a","b","c"]
b = ["m","n","o","p"]
c = [1,2,3,4,"z","y","x","w","aa","ab","ac","ad"]

new_dict = {x: {y:z for y, z in zip(b, c[ind*len(b):])} for ind, x in enumerate(a)}
print(new_dict)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create and empty dict and use nested for loops to add each element from the lists in the format you want. It would look like:

```
d = {}
for i in range(len(a)):
    sub_dict = {}
    for j in range(len(b)):
        sub_dict[b[j]] = c[4i + j]
    d[a[i]] = sub_dict
```

Then, `d` should be the dictionary you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

```py
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
b = ["m", "n", "o", "p"]
c = [1, 2, 3, 4, "z", "y", "x", "w", "aa", "ab", "ac", "ad"]

dic = {}

for idx, key in enumerate(a):
    dic[key] = {}
    for idy, sub in enumerate(b):
        dic[key][sub] = c[idy + len(b) * idx]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(dic)
```

Using `len(<subkey list>)` makes it more flexible therefore if you increase `b` into `["m", "n", "o", "p", "q"]` (obviously with having `len(<all items>) % len(<subkey list>) == 0` preserved) then it still works fine for larger/smaller `c`.

Output:

```
{'a': {'m': 1, 'n': 2, 'o': 3, 'p': 4},
 'b': {'m': 'z', 'n': 'y', 'o': 'x', 'p': 'w'},
 'c': {'m': 'aa', 'n': 'ab', 'o': 'ac', 'p': 'ad'}}
```

With larger:

```
b = ["m", "n", "o", "p", "q"]
c = [1, 2, 3, 4, "z", "y", "x", "w", "aa", "ab", "ac", "ad", "ae", "af", "ae"]
```

```
{'a': {'m': 1, 'n': 2, 'o': 3, 'p': 4, 'q': 'z'},
 'b': {'m': 'y', 'n': 'x', 'o': 'w', 'p': 'aa', 'q': 'ab'},
 'c': {'m': 'ac', 'n': 'ad', 'o': 'ae', 'p': 'af', 'q': 'ae'}}
```

As comprehension:

```py
pprint({
    key: {
        sub: c[idy + len(b) * idx]
        for idy, sub in enumerate(b)
    }
    for idx, key in enumerate(a)
})
```